# why doesn't this method of sorting raster objects work in R?

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm working on a project that has large raster objects that are associated with variables and modified inside a function. I already sort the variables I need inside the function but I now want to return not just the sorted matrix of my variables but the raster associated with those values.  I could run the function twice and return the second object I want in the second iteration but that seems terrible and a waste of time.  I am very new to programming and R is my first language.  This code below throws the same error as my more complicated function,

"Error in temp2[i, ] = t(as.matrix(temp)) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix "

Any advice would be very helpful, thank you.

```
require('raster')

r1 <- raster(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmn=0, xmx=10)
Test = function(x,y,z){
  temp = matrix(NA,4,length(x))
  temp2 = matrix(NA,4,length(x))
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    temp=c(r1,x[i],y[i],z[i])
    temp2[i,]=t(as.matrix(temp))
  }
  return(temp2)
}

x = c(1,2,3,4)
y = c(1,2,3,4)
z = c(1,2,3,4)

final answer = Test(x,y,z)
```

Comment: What is `temp` supposed to be? You are appending an S4 object to a series of numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not clear at all. But here is how you can sort raster values

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
ss <- calc(s, sort, na.last=TRUE)
```

Comment: Maybe what I should have asked is if there was a way to store both a raster file like I have above in the same matrix/dataframe/whatever and then sort that object by the numeric values in the same row as the raster objects.  Thanks for making the attempt.